# Limiting input to just a, b, or d

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm creating a multiple choice quiz application and I'm trying to crate validation. The choices the user must chose between is a,b,c or d and I need to limit the input to these choices using try and catch. The problem is that the variable type of these are strings and have to be strings. The problem is the program is accepting any string( as it should). But is there a way to limit it to just these 4 choices? I tried forcing the program to go to catch if letter didn't == a, b, c, or d but no joy.

```
string[] QuestNums;
        string[] QuestLevel;
        string[] Quest;
        string[] QuestAns;

        QuestNums = new string[50];
        QuestLevel = new string[50];
        Quest = new string[50];
        QuestAns = new string[50];
 while (level == "1")
            {


                Console.Clear();


                Random rnd = new Random();
                int level1_rand = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                AmountAsked++;
            begin:
                try
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\nLevel: 1 \t Score: {0} \tMaximum Questions Remaining: {1} ", score, 20 - AmountAsked);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0}", wrong);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n{0}", Quest[level1_rand]);
                    Console.Write("\nAnswer: ");
                    string selection = Console.ReadLine();
                    string decider = QuestAns[level1_rand];

                    if (selection == decider)
                    {

                        level = "2";
                        score = score + 1;
                        if (score >= 50)
                        {
                            Passed();
                        }
                    }

                    if (selection != decider)
                    {
                        fail = fail - 1;
                        wrong = wrong + 1;
                    }

                    if (selection != decider && AmountAsked > 19 || selection == decider && AmountAsked > 19 || fail == 0)
                    {
                        Failed();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, press any key to try agiain");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    goto begin;
                }

                }
```

Comment: Is this a console application? WPF? Show us the code where you're capturing user input.

Comment: why do you want to limit the choices using the try catch ? could you please provide a code

Comment: Add an enum and use enum.Parse to capture it.

Comment: Is it a strict requirement to use Try / Catch?

Comment: Actually, you should NOT use exceptions to validate user input. Exceptions are for exceptional errors.

Comment: It is a console application, ill put the cod up now. It isn't strictly try/catch but it is the only one I am familiar with.

Comment: @COYG Please don't post a wall of text, most of that code is irrelevant. Post a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dcastro I've taken note, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use exceptions (i.e., try/catch blocks) to validate user input. Exceptions aren't exactly cheap to instantiate and throw and they're supposed to be used in *exceptional, unexpected cases* (i.e., can't connect to a database, failed to save a file to disk).

User input is generally not considered an exceptional, unexpected case - users often get it wrong.

Instead, you could just have a list of valid inputs, and check if the user's input is part of the list.

```
using System.Linq;

static void Main()
{
    var validInputs = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    //validate and retry
    while(! validInputs.Contains(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input was not valid. Please try again.");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //do something here with the valid input
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following algorithm

```
bool inputIsValid=false;
do
{
   var input=ReadInput();

   inputIsValid=ValidateInput(input);
}
while(inputIsValid==false);
```

*Or like Richard suggested with fewer lines

```
    string input = null;
    do{
        input = ReadInput();
    } while (!ValidateInput(input));
```

ValidateInput() could use the try/catch block or something else.
It must returns false if is it invalid or else true

something like this

```
string ReadInput()
{
  return Console.ReadLine();

}

bool ValidateInput(string inputString)
{
     return inputString=="a" || inputString=="b" || inputString=="c" || inputString=="d" ;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `inputIsValid` local, just put the check in the loop condition: `… } while (!ValidateInput(input))`.